# foreach() Invalid argument supplied

Tags: php

I have this code that works for my friend but when I run it, it gave this Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp64\www\DVD_show.php on line 10

What is the problem?

```
    '''
    <?php
    try {
        /*** connect to SQLite database ***/
        $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:dvd.db");
    //echo("ok");
    if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    $name=$_GET['name'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM DVD where name='".$name."'";
    }else $sql = "SELECT * FROM DVD";
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
            {
            print 'dvds[index++]="#'.$row['name'] ."#".$row['director']. "#".                 $row['price']."#".$row['stock'].'#";<br>';
            //dvds[index++]="#Life is Beautiful#dvd1#10.5#10#history#Roberto Benigni#";
            }
    
        /*** close the database connection ***/
        $dbh = null;
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
    <form action="http://127.0.0.1/DVD_show.php" method="get">
     <p>Please input DVD name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
    
     <p><input type="submit" /></p>
    </form>
    '''
```

Answer (score 4):

`$dbh->query($sql)` will return you [Statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php). You should use `fetch` or `fetchAll` to get the results. While `fetch` will return only one - so not iterable, you should use `fetchAll`, which always returns array.

Answer (score 0):

The dbh-> query is wrong at this place as it only returns a statment but not something you can use with foreach

You first need to  use the fetch() or fetchAll() methods

Please see changed code.

NOTE:  If you have a HIGH number of results it is not recommended to use fetchAll as it loads the wohle dataset . then better use fetch() and while like shown in the example ar the link below.

```
  <?php
    try {
        /*** connect to SQLite database ***/
        $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:dvd.db");
    //echo("ok");
    if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    $name=$_GET['name'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM DVD where name='".$name."'";
    }else $sql = "SELECT * FROM DVD";
    
//change this 
    
$data =  $dbh->query($sql) ->fetchAll();
        foreach ($data as $row)

//changes end 
            {
            print 'dvds[index++]="#'.$row['name'] ."#".$row['director']. "#".                 $row['price']."#".$row['stock'].'#";<br>';
            //dvds[index++]="#Life is Beautiful#dvd1#10.5#10#history#Roberto Benigni#";
            }

        /*** close the database connection ***/
        $dbh = null;
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
    <form action="http://127.0.0.1/DVD_show.php" method="get">
     <p>Please input DVD name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>

     <p><input type="submit" /></p>
    </form>
    '''
```

please see:

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select